# Parsing xml using Hadoop, how difficult or easy it is when compared to HTML?

Tags: xml, hadoop

Is parsing xml file in Hadoop tiresome, in terms of the APIs available when compared to HTML? I'm doing a project where I'm parsing xml files and in future have to shift to Hadoop to do the same. Some help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [XmlInputFormat](https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/classifier/bayes/XmlInputFormat.java), a XML loader used in Mahout that is usable outside of Mahout. This should make it pretty easy.

Comment: Will try it out an update. But, in general does hadoop provides more support for HTML?

Comment: In general, Hadoop doesn't support for anything. You have to find loaders or utilities to support the actual data processing.